# Bluetooth module HC-05 not finding mobile phones, only PC

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I put the HC-05 in the AT mode with arduino and the comands:

```
AT+CMODE=1
AT+ROLE=1
AT+INQM=0,10,48
AT+CLASS=0
AT+INIT
AT+INC
```

It responds "OK" after all till AT+INC, and after this, shows only my notebook's adress, but it has many other mobile phones near with bluetooth on (I can find with my cell phone) and they are not found. Why? Someone help me please

Comment: Bluetooth maybe on, but some phones are "invisible" until you put them in "other Bluetooth devices can find me" -mode. Current iPhones are visible when Bluetooth is on but, Androids for example, (at least 7.0 upwards) are visible only when you have the Bluetooth settings screen open.

Comment: I'll make my comment an answer then, which you can mark as correct, so other people with the same problem can find the solution here. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth maybe on, but some phones are "invisible" until you put them in "other Bluetooth devices can find me" -mode.

Current iPhones are visible when Bluetooth is on but, Androids for example, (at least 7.0 upwards) are visible only when you have the Bluetooth settings screen open.